# Tensorflow tf.math.tanh properly scale network output without requiring large batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement a network presented in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.01549.pdf).
This excerpt has a describing image and is accompanied by an explanation. 
[image] 
The input is a feature of 353 floats and the label is a float (-1500, 1500) scaled to `-1, 1`.
The output should also be scaled between `-1, 1`. I used `tf.math.tanh()` to do this. 
However, the only outputs I get are `-1` and `1` but nothing inbetween.
The reason is because when printing the output of the second to last layer I get an array of arrays e.g. :

```py
[[-5670.9859206034189]
 [-3783.2489875296314]
 [6674.3844754595357]
 [-1985.6217861227797]
 [5615.7066561151887]]
```

This, as far as I know, causes `tf.math.tanh` to execute on each individual value in the array. Resulting in either a `1` or a `-1` depending on wether the input is negative or positive.

Since all labels are between `-1500` and `1500` inclusive and normalized to `-1` and `1`. I could opt to add `-1500` and `1500` to every value and feed it through the `tanh` function. This would result in a properly scaled value, even if it goes out of bounds because it could at max be `1` or `-1`.
However, this approach is probably slower than manually doing the scaling of the value without the use of tanh, but just dividing the value by `1500` and capping it at `1` and `-1`.

Another option would be to add all the values in a single array and run that through the `tanh` function. But this feels intuitively wrong. Imagine the array: `[200, 300, 400, 500]`. `Tanh` would scale the `500` to a `1`, while in reality a `1500` should equate to a `1` - thus giving a wrong label. This means that `tanh` would depend a lot on batch size e.g. a 1000 samples would probably give better results than a 100 samples. Inference would have the same issues and require that I always use a large batch size.

What is a proper solution for this problem?

This is part of my network code, I omitted some layers for brevity.

```py
class FullFullyConnectedOutputLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(FullFullyConnectedOutputLayer, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(input_shape[-1] + 1)
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal((input_shape[-1], 1), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(1), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.matmul(input, self.w) + self.b

class FullNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, ):
    super(FullNetwork, self).__init__(name='')

    self.inputLayer = FullFeatureLayer()
    self.hiddenLayer1 = FullFeatureLayer()
    self.hiddenLayer2 = FullFullyConnectedFeatureLayer()
    self.outputLayer = FullFullyConnectedOutputLayer()

  def call(self, input):
    x = self.inputLayer(input)
    x = self.hiddenLayer1(x)
    x = self.hiddenLayer2(x)
    x = self.outputLayer(x)
    return tf.math.tanh(x)

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

fullNetwork = FullNetwork()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
fullNetwork.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(), metrics=["accuracy"])

#epoch is 1 for debugging, batch_size is yet to be determined but probably 1000
fullNetwork.fit(feature_array[:10], score_array[:10], epochs=1, batch_size=5)
```

Comment: scaling the target and apply a tanh as the last activation is ok for your problem... what sounds strange is the extreme high values you obtain (-5000,6000,-3000,4000)... have you tried to investigate why this happens? For example did you scale your input features or something strange happens in your custom layer? (another question which is not related to the solution... why accuracy as metric?)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani could you elaborate on the large values please? Why is this not normal?

Comment: what you are trying to do is not an optimal solution... you are trying to manipulate the outputs in order to suit them inside a desired range and correctly apply tanh. this can work but can negatively influence the train. you can have large values but this is not your case unfortunately, they are the cause of the bad results (always -1 or 1). so I repropose my questions... have you tried to investigate why this happens? For example, did you scale your input features or something strange happens in your custom layer?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I have been rewriting the whole network in Tensorflow 1. Also in TF 1 it is not possible to do tanh because when doing inference only a single value is being outputted thus resulting in -1 or 1. The solution was to do a normalization layer where I scale it back by dividing by 1500(also done on input labels) and then setting the min -1 and max -1. This is something that is working now and is training properly. However, I still don't know what you mean by high values are bad, why is taht?

Answer (score 0):

When using layers, each layer is matrics muliply of the of previous layer input with the weights.
So you can get big value, even you have "good" weights.

When tanh get inputs of even >10, because it is base on exponent it easily returns 1 on every values that is big (mostly range of -2 to 2).

It can get only small values.

So, what if the sum of the rate is low than 1, and each input node is also less than 1, you cannot reach a sum value greater than 1, and that's what I suggest.
Few thing you can do:

1. Use sofmax for the activation function
2. Scale the input values by maxscale (scale input range to output range).
3. You can check the range sum - also you can devide it by the sum you check.
4. Best , and what I suggest,is to do the softmax on the input (it is first input transformation), and xavier with scale of -2..2, so you ensure the output be -2..2 which is best of tanh.
   tanh is a bit linear for this range, so next layers will also keep small range (keeping sum of "1" at maximum).

Any layer, except the last - use tanh.
Last layer use softmax (that's the best approach).
Derivative of softmax is little complicate, so better you learn about this.

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative

It is imporant that you won't do manipulation on output after calculating it. That breaks, when you need propogation back.

Good luck.